# how to tell talend not to hold data while being joined

Tags: talend

I am asking how to do something in talend that is a feature in datastage.

I am seeing a talend job where if I am going to perform a join or lookup, talend tries to "memorize" the entire lookup or reference dataset proir to the join.  My datasets are too large for talend to 'memorize' and kills the job.

In datastage, I can avoid this by having sort stages in front of the join stage, and the join stage monopolizes this by using a "sorted join", whereas the entire dataset isn't held in memory, but is immediately joined and sent ot the next stage while the join is in progress, saving mmory.

How do I accomplish this in talend?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you are retrieving 180 million records from database it might affect ETL performance so this kind of join you can do in database server also

Answer (score 0):

I think you can

- Use the temporary file storage option of the "tmap" that will store on disk.
- Enlarge buffer size in "tmap".
- Or maybe the component "tmemorize"

[image]

Comment: when you have a table with 180Mil records, is that what you put in the buffer?

Comment: when you have a table with 180Mil records you don't pull the data out to Talend. You put the "smaller" data next to it and let the database do the join.